# I have an issue displaying the user's current location on Google Maps in my Android app. Can anyone tell me what I need to do with my code

Tags: android

This is the Code for my MapActivity. It is made to just track user location but it shows location only when there is movement but when i added code to show current location on app launch, it started crashing.

```
    import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    LocationManager locationManager;

    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    {

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        } else {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

            } else {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

                Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));


            }


        }


    }
}
```

The issue is , i was able to get location while changing and sending location from Emulator but when I add the else part to show the current location the app is crashing.

This is the error am getting while the app is launched.

2019-03-06 01:50:39.000 24094-24094/com.example.userlocationdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.userlocationdemo, PID: 24094
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.userlocationdemo/com.example.userlocationdemo.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.userlocationdemo.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:94)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get get latitude from null object of location in the oncreate method of MapsActivity at line 94 as mentioned in the log print

> android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference at com.example.userlocationdemo.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:94)

Comment: i have used this piece **Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);** to get my current location and set the latitude and longitude in the Latlng.  I tried to get the lat and land in double and it worked **Double lat = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
                Double longi = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();** but the app crahses when i try to display it.

Comment: first of all i would recommend you to use double permitive data type instead of  Double object that wrap signle permitive date type double, 2nd is that your lastKnowLocation is null... please put a null check before you get latitude longitude from lastKnowLocation